# Joomla custom authentication plugin only for frontend

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, plugin, authentication

I've created a custom authentication plugin and it works well. The plugin is in the plugins folder plugins/authentication.

Now I face the problem, when I would like to login in my backend, then the plugin will be initiated and my login into the backend fails.

How can I make the plugin only working for my frontend or by using my component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restrict the plugin so that it only gets initiated in the frontend only, by using:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();

if($app->isSite())
{
    // Your plugin code
}
```

or to initiate for a specific component

```
$jinput      = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$component  = $jinput->get('option');

if($component == 'com_content')
{
    // Your plugin code
}
```

Change `com_content` to the component you wish to check for.

Hope this helps

Comment: The plugin is created along the advisory of https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_an_Authentication_Plugin_for_Joomla. In the plugin, there is a function 'onUserAuthenticate' but I did also several functions in addition. I've used your first solution. I did this solution in every function of this plugin. Iam not sure, whether I did the most elegant implementation, but otherwise I came up with errors. Thx

Comment: @Perino - oops, I just spotted a mistake in the 2nd code snippet which I've now updated

Comment: thx Lodder, no worry about that, I did the needed customizing on that :)